# @Cacheable in Spring Cache Stores value in redis outside cache . How do i put it inside cache in redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-cache

```
@Override
@Cacheable("stu")
public EmployeeEntity getEmployee(Integer id) {

    return employeeDAO.findById(id).get(); 
}
```

Above code save the key in redis in this format "stu::7" 
here "stu" is the name of the cache and 7 is the key but it stores the cache name and id as one key.

but i want to store in this format in redis STU ->7
Stu should be name of the cache and inside that all the key value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom key generator to `@Cacheable` annotation where you can customise it as you want: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#keyGenerator--

```java
@Cacheable(value = "stu", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
```

Where `customKeyGenerator` is the name of your custom key generator bean.

Comment: yes but it will only change the name of the key it will not generate the cachestore . I want structure like    (this is cashe )employe ->  <id,name>(its map).   Instead it is creating key outside like "employee:id" :name

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, because docs tell that

> Default is "", meaning all method parameters are considered as a key, unless a custom keyGenerator() has been configured.

It's trivially, but try to set key and cache name explicitly if you don't try it before

```
@Cacheable(value = "stu", key = "{#id}")
public EmployeeEntity getEmployee(Integer id) {
    return employeeDAO.findById(id).get(); 
}
```